# Get throwable class object from String className

Tags: java

Given a string like `com.abc.XYZException` I'd like to get a throwable class that can be resolved from the class path with that string as class name.

```
private Class<? extends Throwable> getExceptionClass(String className){
    return Class.forName(className);
}
```

This snippets cant be compiled because `Class.forName(className)` returns `Class<?>` but `Class<? extends Throwable>` is required. How do I return `Class<? extends Throwable>` ?

Comment: `Class.forName()` loads any class, no matter whether it extends `Throwable` or not. Hence you cannot really make it compile time safe (a standard problem when using reflection API). You should be able to make an unchecked cast which will solve compilation problem, but if `XYZException` is not `Throwable`, you will get exception at runtime.

Comment: Cast it: `return (Class<? extends Throwable>) Class.forName(className);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As also suggested in a comment (unchecked cast of the returned class), this should be what you require in order to let it be compiled:

```
private Class<? extends Throwable> getExceptionClass(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    return (Class<? extends Throwable>) Class.forName(className);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The unchecked cast is unavoidable but you could do things safer by checking that the input is conform before casting it.
You could indeed use `isAssignableFrom()` method of `Class` to check that the `Class` instance loaded is a subclass of the `Throwable` class.

```
  public Class<? extends Throwable> getExceptionClass(String className) {
    try {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
        if (!Throwable.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("error in the provided classname");
        }
        return (Class<? extends Throwable>) clazz;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // handling the exception
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick;

```
private Class<? extends Throwable> getExceptionClass(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException{
    return (Class<? extends Throwable>) Class.forName(className);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or without class cast you could make it return any class type using [wildcard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html):

```
   private Class<?> getExceptionClass(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException{
            return Class.forName(className);    
   }
```